# How to parse a html string using python scrapy

Tags: python, dictionary, scrapy, html-parsing

I have a list of html input elements as below.

```
lists=[<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="jZdkrMumEBeXQlUTbOWfInDwNhtVHGSxKyPvaipoAFsYqCgRLJzc">,
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">,
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">,
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary">]
```

From these I need to extract the attribute values of **name**, **type**, and **value**

For eg:
Consider the input `<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="jZdkrMumEBeXQlUTbOWfInDwNhtVHGSxKyPvaipoAFsYqCgRLJzc">`
then I need  output as following dictionary format
{'csrf_token':('hidden',"jZdkrMumEBeXQlUTbOWfInDwNhtVHGSxKyPvaipoAFsYqCgRLJzc")}

Could anyone please a guidance to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use the Beautiful Soup Python library (https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) to get the HTML content and the values of the elements. There are functions already created for that purpose.